# Either one of two buttons on form needs to be clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I have two button on a form which look as follows:

```
<button name="option" id="option" value="A" class="btn btn-outline-primary" onclick="storeTime()" > Select Option A</button>

<button  name="option" id="option" value="B" class="btn btn-outline-primary" onclick="storeTimeB()" > Select Option B</button>
```

They share id such that if the user clicks one of them then the variable option takes in either the value A or B.  The page where the form is has a timer and I would like that, when the countdown is finished, the form does not submit if non of the buttons is pressed. The way I tried to achieve this is by putting the following on a script:

`document.getElementById("option").required=true`

Unfortunately, that does not do the job. Does anyone have a better option?
Thank you!

Comment: they should not share id. not any element.

Comment: and I don't think required has any effect on button.

Comment: It seems that you need [radio-buttons](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio) here.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML id attribute is used to specify a unique id for an HTML element. You cannot have more than one element with the same id in an HTML document.
Use the following method :

```
document.getElementsByClassName('className');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use buttons for this, you should use something like a classname or other attribute. ID's are meant to be unique for each element. Here's an example using a classname and [document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

```js
let storedVal = ''
document.querySelectorAll('.option-btn').forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener('click', e => {
  storedVal = e.target.value;
}))

function submit() {
  console.log('storedVal:', storedVal);
  if (storedVal == '') {
    console.log('no value');
    return;
  }
}
```

```html
<button value="A" class="btn btn-outline-primary option-btn"> Select Option A</button>

<button value="B" class="btn btn-outline-primary option-btn"> Select Option B</button>

<hr>

<button value="B" class="btn btn-outline-primary " onclick="submit()"> Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not recommended to share IDs to multiple elements, but this is a simple example of how to do it.

```js
        let btns = document.querySelectorAll('#option');
        let selectedValue = '';
        btns.forEach(function (btn) {
            btn.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                let option = e.target.value;
                selectedValue = option;
            });
        });

        document.getElementById('myform').addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
            if (selectedValue === '') {
                alert('Please select an option');
                e.preventDefault();
            } else {
                alert('You selected ' + selectedValue);
            }

        });
```

```html
    <form method="post" id="myform">
        <button name="option" id="option" value="A"> Select Option A</button>
        <button name="option" id="option" value="B"> Select Option B</button>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

Also, you can use radio buttons instead of buttons.

```js
 let options = document.querySelectorAll('.option');
        let selectedValue = '';

        document.getElementById('myform').addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
            options.forEach(function (option) {
                if (option.checked) {
                    selectedValue = option.value;
                }
            });
            if (selectedValue === '') {
                alert('Please select an option');
                e.preventDefault();
            } else {
                alert('You selected ' + selectedValue);
            }

        });
```

```html
    <form method="post" id="myform">
        <input type="radio" class="option" name="radio" value="A" required> SELECT A
        <br>
        <input type="radio" class="option" name="radio" value="B" required> SELECT B
        <br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```